# iOS - Deleting pictures after syncing with iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes, mac

After syncing my iPhone with iTunes, if I delete my pictures from the device, will they also be removed from my Mac on the next sync?

Is there a way to delete my pictures from the iPhone, but keeping them on my Mac?

Answer (score 1):

If iCloud Photo Library, iCloud Photo Sharing, and Upload to My Photo Stream is off, deleting the pictures you import either via Photos app or Image Capture won't delete them from your computer the next time you connect your iOS device (or in the time between), as there is no library sync in place.

Answer (score -3):

Just plug in the phone and then copy and paste to your Mac. The. You are safe to delete.